# Can Symfony run Java jobs over Beanstalk?

Tags: java, php, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on a Symfony 3 (PHP) project.

I would like to launch a Java executable using parameters I got from Symfony.

*Some informations to consider:*

- The executable generates a file as an output.
- Execution can take several minutes depending on the input parameters.
- Multiple users can trigger the execution simultaneously.

I'm looking for a long-term sustainable solution. Do you have any advice?

After some research on [queues.io](http://queues.io/), I found out that Beanstalk for PHP seems to be fitting my needs, but I would like to confirm or infirm this position with you.

What would you do in a similar case?

Comment: its php, just use php to execute a command line string? the fact that you're using symfony as a framework shouldn't matter.

Comment: you can execute command using http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php, if your java have long time operations maybe add task to db or file and using cron execute java program.

Comment: Yes, message queue is a solution for you. Well known are RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ for example. It won't block http request of your users which is great. You just send a message to the queue and worker on the other side will react on it. It doesn't depend on Symfony or PHP. You just need to track a state of particular transaction and send a notification or update some database status when file is ready. You can't do this with `exec` or similar function.

Comment: @kba it seems you understood me well !
I'm looking for a system that can enqueue my tasks (like workers I assume) and you're right when you said that I want a communication back ! I'd like to inform my user of the process progression, is it possible ?
And yes it is to avoid blocking http request, this exactly why I'm looking for a system like that.

To track those transactions don't I need to use the same language as my web framework (meaning PHP because of symfony) ?

Plus I'd like to offer the generated file by download to my user.

Comment: @DevDonkey & seti you're right mentioning exec command but it isn't enough for what I'm looking for.

Comment: There are at least two solutions: first - create second queue which will be handled by PHP application part (Java worker let's know the job is done) or let Java worker modify the completness flag directly in database. I'd preferred first one - it's completely up to you.

Comment: @eRIZ I'm not sure what's the point of the 2nd queue.
Do you mean that the second queue is like a watchdog, monitoring the execution to see if it's done or not ?

Comment: @Fikkwix - nope. Each queue acts as one-way "message bus". Use first one to schedule a task. Second one - as "confirmation". (all just for keeping all tasks async)

Comment: Worker can be written in any language but it could be also Symfony console action in the same project. It could share same database with main web app. Then, state tracking is just about checking any status in any table with generated files for example.

Comment: And what about the [Symfony Process Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html), will it do the trick ?

Does anyone has ever used it ?

Comment: @Fikkwix It could be also possibility if async mode will work as expected. I don't have personal experience with this library.